# How to run Java code using SAS (WPS) without JCL

Tags: java, sas, mainframe, jcl, wps

Am try to call the java application using SAS(WPS). Java application will return some value/outfile. I need to read the same via SAS and comparing the result with existing values.

Reference Link: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/241-30.pdf

Thanks!
Bharathi

Comment: You should include what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the Java application using an X command or SYSEXEC statement. Easiest method is if outputs an output file and then you import that. If it's direct output you likely want to use a PIPE approach instead. The variable `_infile_` will have the output from the OS command, in this case the Java application.

https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2016/03/11/using-a-pipe-to-return-the-output-of-an-operating-system-command-to-sas-software/

```
filename myfiles pipe "your command to the OS";                                                                                                    

data results;                                                                                                                            
  infile myfiles truncover;                                                                                                             
  input; 
  x = _infile_;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
run;
```

Comment: I have used an X command to connect Java. 
X "-Djava.class.path= /BatchJava/lib/apps/helloWorld.jar";

X "Jreoptions =(-Djava.class.path=                                    
            '/u/@C7633/BatchJava/lib/apps/helloWorld.jar')";                 

Getting below error:
ERROR: Failed to launch command : An internal error occurred invoking the command.

Please Note: We are using ZOS.

Comment: Does the command work from the commandline on that server or computer?